# ffmpeg: Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 - Video: none (H265 / 0x35363248)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, h.265

I am trying to find a way to concatenate videos I am getting from an NVR. To my understanding, the video is encoded with H265, but I am not able to find more information on the specific codec (0x35363248). Below is the dump from ffprobe

```
  ffprobe version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.1_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -fno-stack-check' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
{
[avi @ 0x7fb1be803a00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none (H265 / 0x35363248), none, 1920x1080, 88 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 01:00:08.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 93 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: none (H265 / 0x35363248), none, 1920x1080, 88 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 0
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_tag_string": "H265",
            "codec_tag": "0x35363248",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "level": -99,
            "r_frame_rate": "1000000/33333",
            "avg_frame_rate": "1000000/33333",
            "time_base": "33333/1000000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 108245,
            "duration": "3608.130585",
            "bit_rate": "88064",
            "nb_frames": "108245",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "input.avi",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "avi",
        "format_long_name": "AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "3608.130585",
        "size": "42339330",
        "bit_rate": "93875",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "encoder": "Lavf58.29.100"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to force hevc as the encoder and then copy the file stream to a new container, but I am still not able to play the file from QuickTime or VLC. In VLC specifically, I am able to open the video and navigate using the scrollbar but the stream stays frozen.

Is there a way that I could salvage the videos without re-encoding (i.e. by correcting the encoder information)?

Comment: Lazy suggestion is to try the `-analyzeduration 100M -probesize 100M` input options.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I got the same output